# Given the conditions below a triangle determine which type of triangle meets these conditions

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Suppose there is a triangle $ABC$ of sides $a, b, c$ and circumradius

$R$, such that $R ⋅ (b + c) = a \sqrt{b ⋅ c}$

We can say that ABC is (Answer:an isosceles right triangle)

By geogebra I can identify that it would be an isosceles right triangle but I could not demonstrate algebraically

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the law of sines, $a/\sin A = 2R$. Therefore, the triangle satisfies
$$
\sin A = \frac{b+c}{2\sqrt{bc}}
$$
Can you see why this forces the triangle to be isoceles and right?

Comment: No, Can you explain?

Comment: @petaarantes The arithmetic-geometric mean inequality states that $(b+c)/2 \ge \sqrt{bc}$ for all $b, c$, with equality occurring only when $b = c$. This tells us that $\sin A\ge 1$, with $\sin A = 1$ only being true if $b = c$. Since $\sin A \le 1$ by the properties of the sine function, this must be the case.